# What is redirect_uri required by Uber API?

Tags: java, android, uber-api

I was trying to implement Uber API into an android app. I went through the documentation:
https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/android

What is redirect_uri? How can I create redirect_uri for an android app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's implemented by OAuth2 APIs and essentially means the url where the provider (in this case Uber) redirects the status of the auth request on successful or failed authentication.  See [OAuth2 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3) for further info.

In your case it could be your server where you store the access token of the user in your database

Comment: What if I don't have any server to store the access token then what should be my redirect_uri?

Comment: In that case you need to use a different method for authorization. From the [docs](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/android#native-login-with-uber-sso) either implicit grant or SSO with uber app are your options

Comment: I totally agree with you, it is basically a redirect URL where the user is navigated after authorization.